# OS X Lion Safari, Chrome and Firefox crashing while trying to access caixa.gov.br account

Tags: safari, google-chrome, crash, firefox, java

For months I'm having problems accessing this link https://internetbanking.caixa.gov.br/SIIBC/index.processa from caixa.gov.br
It only works when I use Opera, but it fails on Chrome, Safari and Firefox. I don't know if it's the SSL or Java. I have already removed Java, but it didn't work.
Does anyone have any clues?

[Edit]

All browsers are in their latest versions.

[Edit]
The Beginning of the crash error is:

```
Crashed Thread:  20  WorkerPool/-1230196736

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[5305]: garbage collection is OFF
```

Comment: Apart from having a certificate not signed by a standard CA I have no problem accessing with Safari on Lion

Comment: If you create a new user account, then log in as that account, do your browsers still crash?

What versions of Chrome and FF have you installed, and is your Safari up to date?

Are you running any font management software?  Have you tried emptying your various caches with a utility like [Lion Cache Cleaner](http://www.northernsoftworks.com/lioncachecleaner.html)?

Comment: Attempting to load that url results in: Crashed Thread:  5  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** error for object 0x7ff57ad92ca0: pointer being freed was not allocated

Comment: All the browsers are the latest.

Comment: Crashed Thread:  20  WorkerPool/-1230196736

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[5305]: garbage collection is OFF